# modify stat_summary to show only a few point

Tags: r, ggplot2

Currently I have the boxplot below and stat_summary is used to show the quantiles of each distribution as text.

```
group = c( rep(c(1,2),100)   )
r = rnorm(200,50,63)
d = data.frame(  group = group,  r = r  )
head(d)
ggplot(data = d, aes(factor(group), r)) + 
  geom_boxplot()    +
   stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y= quantile,
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.0f", ..y..)),
               position=position_nudge(x=0.33), size=3)
```

[image]

You can see the quantiles are printed as text via the `fun.y= quantile`
line of code.  How can I modify the code to only print the median and the min and max so printing 3 points instead of all 5?

I can create a function and select the quantiles I want

```
ff= function (x)
{
  return(quantile(x)[1])
}
```

and use `fun.y= quantile`  and it will print what I want but how do I incorporate into fun.y directly in the stat_summary call?

Thank you.

Comment: Just put the function in where `quantile` is now: `fun.y = function(x) quantile(x)[c(1,3,5)]`, or more transparently, `fun.y = function(x) quantile(x, c(0, .5, 1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `fun.args` to the `stat_summary` as follows:

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(factor(group), r)) + 
  geom_boxplot()    +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y=quantile,
               fun.args=list(probs=c(0,.5,1)),
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.0f", ..y..)),
               position=position_nudge(x=0.33), size=3)
```